# Is there any way to reroute a method invocation at runtime for NETStandard or NETCore application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, microsoft-fakes

Microsoft Fakes is a tool that can generate Fake Assemblies and utilize the .NET Profiler API to call alternative delegates at runtime, which allows us to replace the invocation on things we normally could not, i.e. `System.DateTime.Now` calls can be set to always return a specific DateTime.

Unfortunately, Microsoft Fakes does not work on NETStandard or NETCore assemblies. I'm wondering if there are any .NET APIs which will allow me to simulate what Microsoft Fakes does and selectively route calls of `System.DateTime.Now` to a custom delegate or to the original method at runtime.

---

I'm aware of ways to redesign the application to minimize the need for something similar to Microsoft Fakes. In fact, the application we have uses Dependency Injection quite a lot, but we chose to avoid going overboard by creating a wrapper around framework classes such as `DateTime`, `HttpClient`, etc. We are literally down to 4 classes which are not fully unit tested because we have no way to isolate those framework classes.

**Please only comments/answers which directly answer this question. No workarounds or alternatives.**

Comment: Another option is to wrap it in a class that implements an interface you can Mock.  Of course that requires hunting down all uses and injecting said class, so that may or may not be worth the trouble.  Alternatively you can change your tests to allow for a tolerance on dates instead of exact values.  Finally having your test code allow you to pass in the dates instead is another work around.

Comment: @juharr: Right, I do know of the alternatives and that would require a redesign. I was hoping to get pointed to some obscure API which would allow me to do what I'm trying to do and replicate how Fakes works.

Comment: I've always considered using Fakes to be a last resort in a tightly-coupled, legacy codebase. It doesn't solve the root problem (which is 'we're writing tightly coupled code'), it solves the symptom ('we have unmockable dependencies').

Comment: @DanielMann: This application was written from the ground up and uses Dependency Injection extremely well. Unfortunately there are about 4 classes which use some dead end framework classes which cannot be mocked in a standard fashion. `DateTime`, `HttpClient`, etc. We contemplated creating a Facade around those classes so we would have `CustomDateTime : IDateTime`, but then our `CustomDateTime` class would go untested, and that seems like overkill.